# What do Turnaround Supervisors do before departure?

Tags: airline-operations, flight-planning, ground-operations

Before the plane is able to take off, what calculations do Turnaround Supervisors have to do and what do they have to check before the plane departs?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the airline and their specific procedures. Turnaround supervisors are in charge of ensuring all ground services are performed correctly and safety. The turnaround supervisor is also responsible to verify the load placed onboard the aircraft matches what was specified on the loading instruction report. Calculations can vary between cargo and passenger flights, but usually cargo involves more calculation and observation to ensure the load is adequately secured. The turnaround supervisor may need to crosscheck the information on the loading instruction report and the loadsheet received in the cockpit to ensure the flight crew received accurate information necessary to calculate takeoff speeds.

The [National Airlines crash in Afghanistan](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Pages/AAR1501.aspx) highlights a serious case where the training of the individuals responsible for securing and calculating the necessary amount of load restraint was grossly inadequate.